# Language Server Protocol: workspace/symbol request

Tags: language-server-protocol

At first glance, my expectation of the `workspace/symbol` request was that a Language Server Protocol server instance would return information about all the text tokens used in source files, such as keywords, names (of variables, functions, classes, methods, interfaces, etc.) function calls (such as `println(...)`), operator symbols (+ - * : & ...) and other such constructs. Rather, the first server I started to explore (fwcd/kotlin-language-server) provided only scant symbol information, mainly declarations of properties, classes and functions.

At second glance, my expectation is now that LSP server instances have huge leeway to interpret what symbols to return and how much information about those symbols should be provided.

As an LSP tool developer, I would like to know what some other server instances provide in the way of symbol information. My guess is "not much" but if that is a bad guess, what a pleasant surprise it will be indeed.

At this point, my understanding is that the server instance can provide only as much symbol information as the underlying compiler technology allows. For modern compilers, like Kotlin, Rust, Go and likely others, this could be a lot of information.

Is this a fair representation of LSP state of the practice at the start of 2021, with respect to source code symbols and associated information provided by the typical LSP server instance?

Comment: Compared to the previous post with several specific questions, this one is worse. The main stream languages have their LSP server implementations open sourced, so if you try to debug a few you can see your expectations/guess/understanding are not on the right track. Too broad to discuss further, but LSP is very specific to IDE features like autocompletion, not merely a thin wrapper over compiler and its AST. So if your requirements do need direct access to AST, then LSP is probably not the way you should go.

Comment: @LexLi you seem to be saying that LSP is for IDEs only. I would grant that IDE flattening is where the technology has found a home. A single IDE can handle many languages because LSP. The technology has empowered a set of tools to get better. My observation is that LSP can help other tools in the same way, in my case code coverage. So I am very much blazing a new trail and looking for information from people like yourself who can save me time and effort in producing a tool that would likely help the community. I may be wrong but I see this as a key service for Stack Overflow.